# Make a Flink Stage wait until its previous stage is complete

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a use-case where state from a previous stage is required in a downstream stage on my streaming pipeline. I would like to add a dependency to the downstream stage so that the upstream/dependent stage is complete before the processing can begin.

Is it possible in Flink?

Answer (score 0):

This how Flink executes non-pipelined regions when running in its batch execution mode.

For streaming this becomes more difficult. There are a few techniques that can be used to bootstrap state. One is to use the state processor API (in a separate batch job) to create a savepoint that contains the state you need for the streaming job.

Another approach, especially useful when the volume of bootstrap data is reasonably small and essentially static, is to not bother using Flink state for this data. Why use something like `MapState` that will have to be checkpointed if you can always restore the state as the job starts by re-ingesting it from the file or kafka topic or database where the ground truth lives? You can load this data into normal java objects in the `open()` method of the function that will be using this data.

All so-called RichFunctions have an `open()` method: e.g., `RichFilterFunction`, `RichFlatMapFunction`, `ProcessFunction`, `KeyedProcessFunction`, `ProcessWindowFunction`, etc. This `open()` method is called once in each parallel instance of the function as the job is being started. There's also a `close()` method that's called during an orderly shutdown.

Comment: The issue is the dependent pipeline is reading from a Kafka topic (from earliest) and is storing that in the Flink `MapState`. So, we need the topic to be fully read before proceeding with the rest of the stages. 

The Kafka topic itself doesn't have a lot of records - probably around 10-20K at the most. So, if we can have the downstream stage (in the pipeline) wait until the read from kafka stage is done, that will solve our problem of state not being available when processing begins.

Comment: Why store that data in `MapState` if it can always be restored from the ground truth in Kafka? Would it be workable to ingest that data in the `open()` method, and store it in vanilla local Map? (What you've asked for is a feature sometimes called "side inputs", and while there's been some progress made in this direction, I don't believe it's all the way there yet.)

Comment: Where is the `open()` method available? In the `FilterFunction`? 

We're ok to process all records again but need to wait until all records from Kafka is restored back to the `MapState`.

Comment: I've expanded my answer. Hopefully it's clearer now, but please follow-up if you have more questions.